# How to sort an NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries using mutiple objectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSmutableArray with dozens of NSMutableDictionaries in it.

Each NSMutableDictionary looks something like this:

```
insComp = F;
insFlow = "suVE";
inID = "SJF42B";
ID = 10000038;
```

I would then like to know how I sort ascending values by several of the NSDictionary keys. for each object instance.

insComp > inID > ID

for example, not using same keys or values

```
-- obj1
var1 = A
var2 = A

-- obj2
var1 = A
var2 = B

-- obj3
var1 = B
var2 = A

-- obj4
var1 = C
var2 = A
```

So that would be sorting first by var1 then every var1-var2 is sorted and so on. I think it's referred to as a tree sort?

Comment: Please elaborate your search criteria..... what should be evaluate first , second and third?

Comment: I have updated wth an conecpt example.

Comment: Can you please explain what output you wanted here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try going with `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor` classes

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                           @[[NSSortDescriptor 
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"insComp" ascending:YES], 
                             [NSSortDescriptor
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Id" ascending:YES]]];
```

There is a nice tutorial dedicated to sorting and filtering and all such kind operations on data collection classes in objective c [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2013/02/05/querying-objective-c-data-collections/).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"insComp" ascending:NO], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"inID" ascending:NO],[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"ID" ascending:NO], nil]];
```

where unsortedArray is your NSMutableArray.

Comment: okay will try this out now. will let you know how i go.. just gotta clean up my coredata then will try it... lol I made a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
 NSArray *firstSort = nil;
    firstSort = [beforeSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id firstObj, id secondObj) {
        NSString *first = nil, *second = nil;
        first = [((NSDictionary*)firstObj) objectForKey:@"Var1"];
        second = [((NSDictionary*)secondObj) objectForKey:@"Var1"];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
    NSArray *secondSort = [firstSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id firstObj, id secondObj) {
        NSString *first = nil, *second = nil;
        first = [((NSDictionary*)firstObj) objectForKey:@"Var2"];
        second = [((NSDictionary*)secondObj) objectForKey:@"Var2"];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```